# Trouble writing zip content to device. Writing as hexa data not xml

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, httpclient

I'm trying to download a zip file that contains an xml file and save the xml file to the device.

I'm able to save the file inside the zip but when I open the file it contains hexa data and not xml.

What I'm doing:

I'm using http client to make a get call. I get stream content from the response and using dependency injection, I pass the stream to a method that writes to the device.

In share code:

```
public static async Task<bool> Download()
{
    var url = "some url";
    HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler()
    {
        AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate
    };

    var httpClient = new HttpClient(handler);

    try
    {
        var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(url);

        var total = response.Content.Headers.ContentLength.HasValue ? response.Content.Headers.ContentLength.Value : -1L;

        var stream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();

        DependencyService.Get<IFileHelper>().WriteToFilePath("download", stream, total);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        //Handle exception
    }

    return true;
}
```

in iOS:

```
public async void WriteToFilePath(string filename, Stream responseStream, long contentSize)
        {
            var downloadFilePath = GetLocalFilePath(filename);

            int receivedBytes = 0;
            using (FileStream fileOut = File.Create(downloadFilePath))
            {
                using (Stream stream = responseStream)
                {
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];

                    for (;;)
                    {
                        int bytesRead = await stream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                        if (bytesRead == 0)
                        {
                            await Task.Yield();
                            break;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(bytesRead);
                            fileOut.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                        }

                        receivedBytes += bytesRead;

                        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("receivedBytes: " + receivedBytes + " contentSize: " + contentSize);
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: are you actually downloading a zipped file?  I don't think AutomaticDecompression works for that scenario

Comment: Yeah, I'm actually downloading a zip file. I have the AutomaticDecompression header because the content type is application/octet-stream. With out the call, the call returns unsuccessful.

Comment: then you'll need an additional step to unzip the file and extract the XML - just writing the stream to disk is only writing the zipped data, not the xml

Comment: How do I go about doing that?

Comment: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Compression/3.9.85

Comment: If you use .NET Standard, GZipStream is most likely available for you to use.

Comment: How would I use gzipstream? get the raw stream for the response stream and use that to create a gzipstream which I then pass to write the file?

Comment: Is their documentation on how to use Microsoft.Bxl.Compression?